# How to center the alignment always

Tags: java, triggers, height, width, processing

I was learning processing and I was trying something with the coordinates, and I am having trouble in aligning to the center of the display window, for reference I have attached the video.

In detailed explanation or example there are two circles starting to slide across X & Y axis,
so when the animation is triggered they will move across the screen and cross exactly at the center of the display window no matter of the ratio of the width and the height, like 500x500 or 500x700 or 700x500.

is there any idea that I can get.

I tried using the translate(width, height) values 
and also some restrictions of the values with pi

rect(height/2, width/2, 2000, 70, 0);
rect(height/2, width/2, 70, 2000, 0);

ellipse(x, width/2, dia, dia);

Answer (score 0):

You can get the display size, using the Java `Toolkit` class:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double height = screenSize.getHeight();
double width = screenSize.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the late answer.

If your problem is that the circles need to be in the middle at the same time, you can use the [lerp()](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html) function.
It takes the minimum value (0), a maximum value (width or height) and a percentage (x/100) and gives the appropriate value.

For example; lerp(0, 100, 0.5) would output 50, because it is in the middle (50% = 0.5) of 0 and 100.

As an example, use x to store the percentage of the way the circles have traveled:

```
ellipse(lerp(0, width, x/100), height/2, dia, dia); //please note that you always set the x-coordinate first.
ellipse(width/2, lerp(0, height, x/100), dia, dia);

if(x < 100)
{
  x++;
}
```

But, because the if-state only contains one statement, the curly brackets are not needed:

```
if(x < 100)
  x++;
```